# Finding a way to Ignore/Remove the if command

Tags: javascript

I am looking to delete/remove the if command below so that on click the submit button the script allows me to move on to the next page by returning the value as true. Does anyone have any suggestions here?

```
function chk_img(el) {
    var img_text = md5(document.getElementById('img_text').value);
    var img_str = document.getElementById('img_str').value;
    if (img_text.length==0 || img_text !== img_str){
        my_alert("Retry");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you perhaps add a tag with the language you're using?

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer Looks like JavaScript. I've made a suggested edit.

Comment: What am i missing here ? and why does this feel like a joke...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```js
function chk_img(el) {
    var img_text = md5(document.getElementById('img_text').value);
    var img_str = document.getElementById('img_str').value;

    // if statement was here; I deleted it

    return true;
}
```

Note: in this version, the first two lines are not needed. And in browsers, the default behavior when clicking on a link is to navigate, so you don't even need to return `true`, and indeed the whole function can be deleted.

```js
// final version

// this space intentionally left blank
```

---

*Edited to add:*

You also expressed interest in *ignoring* the `if` statement rather than deleting it, so here is one way to do that:

```js
function chk_img(el) {
    var img_text = md5(document.getElementById('img_text').value);
    var img_str = document.getElementById('img_str').value;
    /*
    if (img_text.length==0 || img_text !== img_str){
        my_alert("Retry");
        return false;
    }
    */
    return true;
}
```

The `/*` and `*/` mark the beginning and end (respectively) of something called a [multi-line comment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#comments). When the browser runs the function, it will skip all the code between those two marks, literally ignoring it.

---

*Another thought occurs:*

It's possible that the best solution for you is to delete the whole function, but if you do that, you'll probably run into another error:

> ReferenceError: chk_img is not defined

If that happens, it means there is code somewhere that is still trying to assign the `chk_img` function to the click handler, and you'll need to find and disable/remove it. You may be able to just search for the name of the function in your source code.

If you have trouble finding it, and can't find any other way past the `ReferenceError`, you can always restore the function but have it do nothing:

```js
function chk_img(el) {}
```